# What is the right Header Search Path for the Soundcloud sdk iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, sdk, soundcloud

I have read and used the soundclouds sdk documentation but i always come up with the error SCUI.h not found:

[image]

I have tried using different paths like: ' $PROJECT_DIR ' and ' ../** ' but it still doesn't work ! even tried cleaning the project

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way you can make it build.

1) Go to application's framework logical folder.

2) Right click on soundCloud.framework

3) Show in finder command+i  copy the path

4) Add the path in framework search path in build settings

5) Clean and build.

you still can shrunken it with $SRCROOT (instead of /Users/"computer Name"/Desktop/SoundcloudTest). $SRCROOT will give you the project directory.

Comment: path was: /Users/"computer Name"/Desktop/SoundcloudTest